# Parsing error in MyBatis insert into table select with static value

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, mybatis

I get a Parsing syntax error nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Parsing error was found in mapping #{args.employeeType); Employee type is based on user input from screen. When I debug it, I have the Employee type value but it will return parse error.

My mapper function is

```
public void insertPerson(@Param("args") Person form);
```

My Insert SQL is

```
<insert id="insertPerson" parameterType="person.form.Person">
    BEGIN;
        INSERT INTO personTable(
            person_id,
            person_name,
            employee_type
        )
        SELECT
            person_id,
            person_name,
            ${args.employeeType}
         FROM personDB tbl
         WHERE
            tbl.personId = #{args.personId);
    COMMIT;
   </insert>
```

I dont know why I get a parsing error.

Comment: For column names, you need to use `${}` instead of `#{}`. Try `${args.employeeType}` . See this [FAQ entry](https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/wiki/FAQ#what-is-the-difference-between--and-) for why. And you really should not use user input directly in SQL to avoid SQL injections.

Comment: @ave  employeeType is not a column from Db, it is from Person form object. User input on employee type is passed on Person form object and I want to add user inputted employee type value when insert data on personTable.

Comment: Ah, I see. I noticed that you closed the expressions (both expressions) using a parenthesis `)` instead of a brace `}`. Could that be the reason? If not, please add the full stack trace to the question.

Comment: @ave I had it changed now. It works. Thank you